# 'Sharing' class libraries in Visual Studio Online source control

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

We are currently migrating our source control to Visual Studio Online. A feature we had in our old system (SourceGear Vault) was to share projects between solutions. Although this created a folder for our Framework project in each solution it kept it up to date when changes were checked in.

This is useful to us as it allows us to work on the Framework code in all the Solutions that are using it. I know its better practice to just compile the dlls and reference them - at this point in development we want to continue having full code access and debugging in all the solutions using this core framework.

Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: Shared code or pinning will never be implemented in TFVC as it is considered such a bad practice.

Comment: @MrHinsh: Would you elaborate on why you consider shared code (projects/assemblies/libraries) to be a bad practice. In my view at least the concept of shared code is near to—if not at—the heart of the .NET Framework itself. Witness GAC.

Comment: There is no 'code' in the GAC, they are binaries. You should compile your code, package it in Nuget and publish locally. Then take a dependency on that package. Create a DevOps pipeline to publish the package and you have an automated feed from checkin to consumption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the responses. We actually found a solution that works well for us. We branch our framework project into the implementation projects when we want access to the code base. If not we just use the DLLs

If it is then altered and checked into the implementation project it can be merged back with the other Framework branches easily when ready.

This probably wouldn't work well if the Framework code was being developed heavily, as it is now its only undergoing small additions and tweaks so wont be plagued with merge issues.

Comment: I would never recommend this approach as it introduces risk and compromises quality. Daniel Mann has the correct solution above. What you have here is a temporary work around for immature software development teams.

Answer (score 5):

You have a few equally valid options for handling shared projects:

1. Reference the same project from each solution that needs it.

This gives you full control over the source code of the shared project while you work on the consuming solution, and may allow for easier debugging.

The downside here is that maintenance and releases may become trickier if Solution A is being released on Thursday, but Solution B is being released in 3 months and is in the middle of a huge refactoring cycle that has significantly modified Shared Component X, and Shared Component X isn't stable enough to be released.

2. Reference shared components from an internal NuGet repo.

You set up your release pipeline to push the shared components into NuGet as part of your release process (ideally, using a purpose-built release management tool... Microsoft Release Management is what I have in mind here) -- you check the code in, project gets built. Release process packages it up and pushes it into NuGet as a "prerelease" version. You reference the latest version in anything that needs the latest version. 
If you need to reference a known-good, stable version, you just make sure your project is configured to pull a specific version from NuGet.

When you're done, you've tested the shared thing, and you know everything is good, you approve the prerelease version, and the same binaries are repackaged into a "stable" version.

The downside here is that there are some additional software requirements, configuration, and training for your team. This would be my recommended approach.

3. Check binaries into source control.

I don't recommend this one -- you end up bloating your source control repo (and if you're using Git, it's an explicitly stated anti-pattern -- **never** put binaries into Git, it causes long-term severe performance problems), and it's never exactly clear which projects are using which versions of which assemblies. It's a maintenance nightmare.

(1) is the best approach if you're releasing everything in lockstep and don't have to worry about maintaining separate versions.

(2) is the best approach if #1 is false.

(3) is the best approach if #1 is false and you're a time traveler who is posting from 2006.

Comment: I would say if #1 is true then pit everything in on Solution. If you can't then #2 is the correct answer...

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered implementing **Symbol Server** and **Source Server** indexing with the *check-in binaries or NuGet repo* approach?  This allows you to easily get back to the source while debugging and it's coming from a single known location.  Visual Studio Online and Team Foundation Server have built-in support for helping you out with getting this setup during your build process.  Here's more information in a write-up here: [Source Server and Symbol Server Support in Team Foundation Server and Visual Studio Online](http://www.edsquared.com/2011/02/12/Source+Server+And+Symbol+Server+Support+In+TFS+2010.aspx)

[image: Setting up Symbol Server and Source Server with Visual Studio Online and Team Foundation Server]

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree with the majority. I just ran into the same issue. I implemented the Nuget Gallery Site on the internal network. It was a pain to implement, but once implemented, it's easy to use. I created a class library project that implements ADO.Net and the EntityFramework. I bundled it into a NuGet package and uploaded it to the internal NuGet gallery. From there I was able to add a package source to the internal NuGet gallery and grab the package that I uploaded. Very simple and convenient.

I set up the NuGet Gallery with Visual Studios 2017. FYI: Make sure that building the project isn't part of the Publish. It will not render with a ViewHelper.cshtml error.

I created the projects with Visual Studios 2015. I ran the command prompt as administrator. I also had to copy the NuGet.exe file into the directory where the project file existed.

Check out the below links for more information.

[NuGet Gallery](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery)
[Hosting NuGet Gallery](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/wiki/Hosting-the-NuGet-Gallery-Locally-in-IIS)
[Create and Publish Package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package)
[Creating a Package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package)
[Create .Net Standard Package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/guides/create-net-standard-packages-vs2015)